# Is it mandatory to return value according to the ISO C++03

Tags: c++

**According to the ISO C++ standard**, is it mandatory to return value (if we specified that we would return value).

```
int foo()
{
// return i;
}
```

Comment: On all functions other than `main`, yes.

Comment: Think about what would happen if `foo` in your example didn't have the `return` statement, what would the caller of `foo` receive for result? Also read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).